# How to import typeahead when working with typescript and webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, webpack, typeahead.js

I ran `npm install typeahead` and `npm install @types/typeahead`, however I am 
having trouble with importing `typeahead` into my `tsx` module:

```
import * as React from "react";
import "typeahead";

interface IReactTypeaheadInputProps {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    url: string,
    searchField: string,
}

export class ReactTypeaheadInput extends React.Component<IReactTypeaheadInputProps, {}>{

    componentDidMount(): void {
        .
        .
        .
        $("#" + this.props.id).typeahead<string>(typeaheadOptions, datasets);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input id={this.props.id} name={this.props.name}/>
        );
    }
}
```

I've tried:

- various styles of import statements
- adding an alias to my webpack.config.js file, like this:

  resolve: {
      alias: {
          typeahead: 'typeahead.js'
      }
  }

When I use `import "typeahead"`, I get

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function

When I use `import * as typeahead from "typeahead";`, I get

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "typeahead"

I am getting intellisense for the whole `Twitter.Typeahead` namespace (I'm using VS 2017). However I suspect that the npm typeahead package is not official because it is an older version and the name of the file is `typeahead.js` instead of `index.js` in the `node_modules` folder.

I've tried to include the newer version manually but I get the same results.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to import Bloodhound from Typeahead and struggling with the same thing

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't. What I used was to `declare const`s as `any` in order for TS to let me do my work. However, as you can imagine, this does not bring up intellisense.

Comment: Maybe this helps - https://reactkungfu.com/2015/10/integrating-jquery-chosen-with-webpack-using-imports-loader/ - some people get it working with the imports loader